# ASP.NET Core reference my object model library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core app for WebAPI and I have a regular .NET class library containing my object model. Is there an easy way to reference that in my ASP.NET core app? I tried doing "Add Reference" and pointing to the dll in our release folder (this is how we normally go about adding references) but that gave me an error stating that only .NET assemblies could be referenced. It is a .NET assembly (.NET 4.61 - my ASP.NET Core app is targeting the full framework - also .NET 4.61). I also tried adding the existing project to my solution and referencing it as a project reference. This will add it to my project.json but I get an error that it can't resolve the reference. I did follow [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx) guide and it gave me the same error - could not resolve reference. It doesn't seem like it should be this hard to get this to work. I would imagine that most developers would want to abstract their object model out from a particular web app and be able to reference it. At this point, I'm not using anything crazy. I just have a collection of interfaces using standard .NET types. Though down the road I also want to be able to add references to COM libraries (I'm not exactly confident right now that that is going to work). If anyone has any insight for me, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: project.json is deprecated. when did you create your .net core project? have you tried starting afresh with a new project? check out this https://jonhilton.net/2017/03/14/use-asp-net-core-1-1-with-net-4-without-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware that in VS 2017 they went back to .csproj (with a new format). But the wheels grind slowly at my organization. We started the long process of porting from VS 2010 to VS 2015 months ago. There's no way we're going to 2017. And yes, I know VS Code will handle 2017 projects but having to go to management and tell them the  app can't be coded in VS 2015 won't go over well. I mean, in the end if that's the way it is then that conversation will have to happen (either switch to VS Code or go back to ASP.NET MVC/WebApi). But I'm hoping it doesn't come to that.

Comment: give this a go then: https://jonhilton.net/2016/09/07/using-asp-net-core-against-net-4-6/ and make sure your assemblies target the same .net framework version

Comment: Thanks again for the response. It turns out I am able to do it if I make it a project reference. This is not how we normally do things - we have a Release directory and we reference dlls from in there. I think I can work it out, though, to use project references for this app. Interestingly, I had tried that before and my references weren't able to be resolved. But I was trying it by adding an existing project to an app on my D drive. If I create everything together in its own directory on C:, everything resolves fine. So I am still having a config issue getting project references to resolve.

Comment: It looks like I need to modify my global.json file's 'projects' list to be able to find projects in locations outside my ASP.NET Core app directory structure? But I've tried adding an entry to that list (I gave an absolute path to the folder containing the project file for the class library) and it still can't resolve the reference.